# Targeting HTML elements created in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Very first project on my own and I am having a problem when i am trying to target a set of buttons i am creating using JavaScript. The event listener will only fire when i hit the first button that is created. It wont register any other button clicks. What am i missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

JavaScript:

```
function creatButtons() {
    for ( var i = 65; i <= 90; i++ ) {
        let letter = String.fromCharCode( i );
        let button = document.createElement( "button" );
        button.id="buttons"
        button.innerHTML = letter;
        buttonHolder.appendChild(button)
    }
    
}
creatButtons()


// Event listeners
document.getElementById("buttons").addEventListener('click',function(){
     console.log("testing")
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="button-holder"></div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's because multiple elements can't have the same **unique** ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cans simply use [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) instead of an `id` attribute. Also for your `onclick` event you can call a function pass `this` to get the `letter` you clicked.

Also, you [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method to append all your characters to the button holder.

**Demo:**

```js
function creatButtons() {
  let buttonHolder = document.querySelector('#button-holder')
  for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
    let letter = String.fromCharCode(i);
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.className = "buttons"
    button.innerHTML = letter;
    button.onclick = function() {
       getLetter(this) //get letter
    };
    buttonHolder.appendChild(button)
  }

}
creatButtons()

//Get letters
function getLetter(e) {
 console.log(e.innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<div id="button-holder"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks i left out that code  but i did have a variable for buttonHolder up top of the code i forgot to add. I tried to even used class instead of ID but it will only still target the first button created

Comment: @dgm1102 You need to use an `onclick` function for your dynamically created button. Please use the code  `JAVASCRIPT` i have provided. It will work fine. Let me know.

Comment: Okay that worked like charm, I get what you did up until you pass this in the function. But thanks i will study that up and figure out what's going on. Thank you for the help

Comment: @dgm1102 Glad to hear that. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define `buttonHolder`.

```
function creatButtons() {
    var buttonHolder = document.getElementById('buttonHolder'); // add this line
    for ( var i = 65; i <= 90; i++ ) {
        let letter = String.fromCharCode( i );
        let button = document.createElement( "button" );
        button.id="buttons"
        button.innerHTML = letter;
        buttonHolder.appendChild(button)
    }
}
```

Additional note, suggest to use `forEach` instead of `for loop`.

Comment: why `forEach` ?  its slower in performance anyway - old school `for loop` is faster in performance.

Comment: theoretically, `for loop` must return something, `forEach` no need. that's the only difference